# Using ReachDOMClient from a simple CDN static page

Tags: reactjs

On a simple static web page (no server-side rendering, no bundler), I access react and react-dom using

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I can access parts of the API like this:

```
const {
  useMemo
} = React;

const {
  createRoot
} = ReactDOM;
```

This works great, but with the latest version of React@18, you need to import "react-dom/client"

How do you do this in a simple single-page static app?

There doesn't appear to be a way to get "ReactDOMClient" or just "Client" out of the ReactDOM API object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning will be fixed in the next 18.1.
See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24292

Answer (score 2):

CDN's ReactDOM has createRoot function.

```js
const html_root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.createRoot(html_root).render(<App/>);
```

But this way happens warning message.
Because this way isn't fully completed the migration.
Best way is `import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";`
https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/5#discussioncomment-798304

Answer (score 0):

We can continue coding with these CDN https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js,
https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js
without breaking *errors* by ignoring the *warning* until this *warning* is fixed by react org